# Merging JSON properties for two arrays of JSON objects (using ramda)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

Consider that I have two arrays as follows:

```
let a1 = [{id:1, name:'jon'}, {id:2, name:'adam'}]
let a2 = [{id:1, age:42}, {id:2, age:13}]
```

I want to merge the two arrays so the JSON properties get combined into one array; i.e. this is what I want to end up with:

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'jon', age: 42 },{ id: 2, name: 'adam', age: 13 }]
```

Using `Ramda` I can do the following which gives me close to what I want, but annoyingly it's not in an array - it's all JSON

```
R.mergeDeepLeft(a1, a2)
{ '0': { id: 1, name: 'yasin', age: 42 },
  '1': { id: 2, name: 'adam', age: 13 } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `R.values` to convert to array, like this:

```
let a1 = [{id:1, name:'jon'}, {id:2, name:'adam'}]
let a2 = [{id:1, age:42}, {id:2, age:13}]

R.values(R.mergeWith(R.mergeLeft, a1, a2));
```

If you have unordered arrays, you can do this:

```
let a1 = [{id:1, name:'jon'}, {id:2, name:'adam'}]
let a2 = [{id:2, age:13}, {id:1, age:42}]

R.values(R.mergeWith(
  R.mergeLeft, 
  R.indexBy(R.prop('id'), a1), 
  R.indexBy(R.prop('id'), a2)
));
```

Comment: Please note that `R.merge` is deprecated. Also this only works by accident, because the objects in `a1` and `a2` are nicely lined up. If you swap the objects in `a2`, `{id: 1, name: 'jon'}` will be merged with `{id:2, age: 13}` to give `{"age": 13, "id": 2, "name": "jon"}`

Answer (score 4):

I'd do this:

1. concat `a1` and `a2` together. (They don't need to be kept apart)
2. group objects by id and merge those that share the same id.
3. finally get all merged objects out.

```js
const res =
  pipe(
    concat,
    reduceBy(mergeLeft, {}, prop('id')),
    values);

console.log(

  res(a1, a2)

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>
const {pipe, concat, reduceBy, mergeLeft, values, prop} = R;
const a1 = [{id:1, name:'jon'}, {id:2, name:'adam'}];
const a2 = [{id:1, age:42}, {id:2, age:13}];
</script>
```

Comment: Not only a good answer to the question, but one which covers cases where the arrays are in different order, or where either one contains elements not matching any in the other.  It also is easily extended to an array of inputs via `R.reduce(res, [])`.  Nicely done!

Comment: yours is certainly the neatest solution and one I can follow... However, Antons also works, although I'm having difficulty figuring out why!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the most elegant nor extensible solution but I'd use some mapping and the spread operator:

```
let a1 = [{id:1, name:'jon'}, {id:2, name:'adam'}]
let a2 = [{id:1, age:42}, {id:2, age:13}]
let a3 = a1.map(item => {
    return {...item, ...a2.find(item2 => item2.id === item.id)}
})
```

Here's a working Fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/gshfo7pm/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let a1 = [{id:1, name:'jon'}, {id:2, name:'adam'}]
let a2 = [{age:13, id:2}, {id:1, age:42}]

const fn = R.pipe(
   R.map(R.indexBy(R.prop('id'))),
   R.reduce(R.mergeWith(R.mergeDeepLeft), {}),
   R.values
)
    
let newArray1 = fn([a1, a2]);
let newArray2 = fn([a2, a1]);
    
console.log(newArray1);
console.log(newArray2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: very good, your solution works too with the added benefit that the arrays can be in any order and it will still merge by id.. good jwork

Comment: are you sure about that? I tried with swapping the order of a2 and it still worked

Comment: i was replying to someone else who said your solution wouldn't work if order switched but it does. the other guy then deleted his comment by the looks of it

Comment: Yep that comment was mine. I looked through the revisions of this post and they were all fine. I must have been confused with other answers that were flawed. Since that comment was no longer relevant I deleted it. Also lifted my downvote btw.

Comment: Thnx, didn't bother rechecking until @JohnHarrison mentioned it so I added the snippet to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
let concatValues = (k, l, r) =>  r
R.mergeDeepWithKey(concatValues,a1,a2)
```

will produce this

```
{"0": {"age": 42, "id": 1, "name": "jon"}, "1": {"age": 13, "id": 2, "name": "adam"}}
```

it's not exact output but you can start with this

Comment: As for some other answers here, this still relies on both `a1` and `a2` to be sorted by `id`. If you swap the order of the objects in `a2`, you end up with an incorrect merge e.g. `{"age": 13, "id": 2, "name": "jon"}`